# Do I need a global variable or better OO design in this rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, global

I'm writing a rails application that uses the discogs api ruby wrapper by buntine and most of my objects need access to the @discogs object that exists in the controller and represents the entire ruby wrapper and connection to discogs.  Instead of passing @discogs to other objects, which in turn are working with other objects that of course need @discogs passed to them should I be making @discogs a global variable in my application to some extent?

I feel like I'm writing bad code passing this one object around, but I'm also hesitant that about a global scope solution, and I'm not even sure what the reasonable way to do that is in rails.

Advice much appreciated!

Comment: I also don't know the standard and correct answer but what if you make it a method just like we do with `current_user` or a normal method in application controller? All the controllers will have the access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than passing a `@discogs` variable around your application, you can create a global object in an initializer like so:

**config/initializers/discogs.rb**

```
DiscogsWrapper = Discogs::Wrapper.new("My awesome web app")
```

Now you can refer to the `DiscogsWrapper` object in other parts of your application.

**Example 1:**

```
module Artists
  def self.search(name, wrapper = DiscogsWrapper)
    wrapper.search(name)
  end
end
```

**Example 2:**

```
class Artist
  def get
    wrapper.get_artist(discogs_id)
  end

  private

  def wrapper
    DiscogsWrapper
  end
end
```

In my opinion, this approach is reasonable; I've seen it in other applications and it works well.

Hope that helps. Good luck!